# PDF Generation Results in ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE in Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, pdf

When generating a PDF in the browser programmatically (via PHP) the rendered PDF displays fine in both Firefox and Safari, but Chrome returns an ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE. It is a valid PDF - can be opened locally with Adobe Reader/Preview once saved from the working browsers, and will even open in Chrome once the PDF is saved from a different browser.

The PDF file is being read through `file_get_contents()`, is given a current timestamp and then passed to the browser. A workaround would involve saving the file to a temporary spot and redirecting the user (for Chrome, at least) but this is not ideal.

I've researched it and only been able to find [bug reports dating from 2008](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=138).

I have an inkling it's a header error. After the PDF is generated, the following headers are sent to the browser (again working fine in FF, Safari and IE):

```
    header('Content-type:application/pdf');
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

I've also tried adding the following headers after searching on Stack Overflow, but to no avail:

```
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
```

Are there missing headers that Chrome requires? Does anyone have experience with getting dynamically generated PDFs to display in Chrome?

EDIT: One of my more salient questions is what could be causing this to work fine locally in Chrome, but wouldn't work on a server environment.

Comment: Have you tried changing the disposition to attachment? header('Content-Disposition: attachment;; filename="YourFileName"');

Comment: @HNA I have - the same error results in Chrome whether using attachment or not. There are two buttons: "save" which throws in the `header('Content-Disposition: attachment;');` so that the file is automatically downloaded (this is working locally in Chrome, FF, and Safari and it's working non-locally for Safari and Firefox). The other button, "view", just displays the PDF without auto-downloading it. Neither currently work in Chrome in a non-local instance.

Comment: Do you send a `header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($yourfile));` ?

Comment: @maxhb Yes. The following headers are sent with the request:               `header('Content-Type: application/pdf');`
`header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');`
`header('Expires: 0');`
`header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');`
`header('Pragma: public');`
`header('Content-Length: ' . $length);`

Comment: Chrome needs the Status 200 Header at first. This works: header( $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 200 OK' );
        header( 'Content-type: application/pdf' );
        header( 'Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"' );
        header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );
        header( 'Accept-Ranges: bytes' );

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I want to thank everyone for their answers.

It turns out this was not related to the headers. After attempting to change/remove headers in various ways (detecting encoding, trying with and without content-length, etc.) we decided to dig into the deeper httpd logs to see if anything was resolving differently for Chrome.

It turns out that `mod_sec` on our server was flagging the request (only from Chrome for some reason) as an attempt at a file injection attack and was returning a 403 forbidden response. Chrome displayed this as the `ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE` rather than a 403.

The hostname of the CDN  was present in the request (we had ample checking at the endpoint to ensure that the file was indeed an allowed resource), and instead are building the URL out on the server instead.

Comment: how did you solve it? I'm stuck with the same problem.

Comment: I need to know the solution to that issue, I am having the same issue. It is able to display images yet won't display PDF citing the ERR_INVALID_RESPNSE which in reality is 403 error.

Comment: @netrox The solution is contained with the answer. Ours was being thrown due to our CDN's url (AmazonS3) being present in the query. We removed it from the URL, then added it back in at the endpoint.

Comment: What did you mean building the url on the server instead @AndrewKlatzke

Comment: @Pascal We had been sending the entire CDN url in the query. Instead of sending it directly on the request (&key={endpointUrl}/resource) we instead just send the resource handle, figure out out endpoint (CDN url) once the request arrives, concatenate the two and use that version.

Answer (score 12):

In my case I had to **add these 2 parameters to headers** because wordpress was sending 404 code as it didn't recognize the url of my php function:

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf",true,200);
```

as stated in this [answer on wordpress.stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3480/how-can-i-force-a-file-download-in-the-wordpress-backend).

This forces the headers to replace (2nd param `true`) the 404 status code generated by wordpress as it does not recognize the custom url, and sets 200 OK (3rd param `200`).

So it ended being something like this:

```
$pdf_name = "test.pdf";
$pdf_file = "/absolute/path/to/my/pdfs/on/my/server/{$pdf_name}";
header('Content-type: application/pdf',true,200);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$pdf_name}");
header('Cache-Control: public');
readfile($pdf_file);
exit();
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
<?php
$filename = 'Physical Path to PDf file.pdf';
$content = file_get_contents($filename);

header("Content-type:application/pdf");

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header("Content-Disposition:inline;filename='".basename($filename)."'");   
header('Content-Length: '.strlen( $content ));

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile($filename);
?>

<html>
<body>
...
...
...
```

> Make sure that above header code is called before output of PHP script is
>   sent to browser.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've tried and re-tried those headers with no luck. I posted the full list of attached headers in a comment on the original question. Note too that we are not actually "reading" the file out to the browser but are instead reading the PDF, modifying it, and then supplying that newly created file as either an immediate download attachment or in the browser's PDF viewer (it is not saved to disk at any point during this process).