# Laravel pdf generation display (snappy library) returning ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-snappy

I have some trouble trying out the example of the snappy library. when i am trying to display using the getOutput function the browser is returning a ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE. i tried the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599266/pdf-generation-results-in-err-invalid-response-in-chrome) but it doesn't work for me.

here is my code on my function:

```
    // Display the resulting pdf in the browser
    // by setting the Content-type header to pdf
    $snappy = new Pdf('/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf');
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf',true,200);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
    echo $snappy->getOutput('http://www.github.com');
```

Your help/suggestions/advice will be very much apprciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the pdf first at your local storage, and then return the response.

It will look something like this:

```
$snappy = new Pdf('/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf');
$snappy->save('path/to/your/storage');
$response = Response::make(Storage::get('path/to/your/storage'), 200);
$response->header("Content-Type", 'application/pdf');
$response->header("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename=file.pdf');
return $response;
```

Since you are using Laravel I would suggest you use the Laravel wrapper for snappy

[Snappy PDF/Image Wrapper for Laravel 5 and Lumen 5.1](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy)

Answer (score 0):

My guess **wkhtmltopdf**'s binary is missing. 
You can install it by executing this command from the folder where you have your Laravel project:

```
$ composer require h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-i386 0.12.x
```

or for 64-bit system:

```
$ composer require h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 0.12.x
```

Then you need to change this line in your funciton:

```
$snappy = new Pdf('/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf');
```

to

```
$snappy = new Pdf(base_path('vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64'));
```

source: [Wkhtmltopdf binary installation as composer dependency](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy#wkhtmltopdf-binary-as-composer-dependencies)

Comment: thank you @pnsh for your reply .. i had the error fix :) however i need another help when i had this line on my app 

echo $snappy->getOutput('http://myapp.com/generatepdf');

I generates the pdf fine but it shows the login page instead of the page i want to convert on pdf. can you please give me some suggestions how i can do this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: @ShadrachBaldon the output of the pdf depends on what you render on the "geneartepdf" page (parameter of the getOutput method). My guess is this route is under authentication middleware, that's why it redirects you on login page. Since my answer solved your original problem, please consider close this question.