# ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE on Chrome while opening PDF generated through PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-chrome, pdf, html2pdf

I am trying to open a PDF that is dynamically generated by PHP using html2pdf.
It is working well on Firefox and Safari. However on Chrome giving **ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE**.
All was working well before, till we updated our site to CodeIgniter 3.1.4.
Have already searched everywhere and didn't found any suitable solution for my issue.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
function property_pdf_ver2($property_id = FALSE, $tenure_text = FALSE) {
    error_reporting(E_ALL);        
    require_once(APPPATH . 'third_party/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
    $template_pdf = $this->load->view('templates/property-pdf-ver2', $data, TRUE);
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('L', 'A5', 'en', true, 'UTF-8', array(0, 0, 0, 0));
    $html2pdf->setDefaultFont('helvetica');
    $html2pdf->addFont('robotolight', false, getcwd() . '/assets/fonts/robotottf/robotolight.php');
    $html2pdf->addFont('robotomedium', false, getcwd() . '/assets/fonts/robotottf/robotomedium.php');
    $html2pdf->addFont('robotothin', false, getcwd() . '/assets/fonts/robotottf/robotothin.php');
    $html2pdf->WriteHTML($template_pdf);
    $html2pdf->Output('sample.pdf');
    $html2pdf->SetFillColor(0, 128, 190);
}
```

Comment: Can you supply the code you are using with codeigniter for us to help you.

Comment: @timothymarois I have added the controller function to support my question.

Comment: The same problem was answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599266/pdf-generation-results-in-err-invalid-response-in-chrome

Comment: @AgniusSteponavičius I have already gone through that post, but it doesn't made any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's weird but after a careful debugging I found the cause for issue.
The below line was preventing the chrome from loading the PDF. I had to remove it for the function to work.

```
$html2pdf->SetFillColor(0, 128, 190);
```

Thanks all, for your consideration towards my issue.