# Laravel Excel download xls error ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE on Nginx

Tags: php, excel, laravel, vesta

I'm can't download/export xls and xlsx format with Laravel Excel (Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel), when i download always show ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE. but when i'm trying download csv format works fine.

My Configuration :

- Laravel 5.1
- Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel 2.1
- Nginx
- Centos 6.9
- VestaCP as a Panel
- PHP 5.6, 7.0, 7.1 (i'm trying to change PHP version, still can't download xls or xlsx)
- I have also followed the requirements (https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/docs/3.0/getting-started/installation)

And this my code :

```
 Excel::create("Customers", function ($excel) {
        $excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function ($sheet) {
            $sheet->row(4, array(
                'NO.',
                'NAME',
                'DATE',
                'ADDRESS'
            ));
        });
    })->export('xls');
```

How can i fixed this issue ?

Comment: Could you show the code you have done? this will help us

Comment: is `ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE` a chrome browser error? You may not have the right `Content-Type` headers set eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599266/pdf-generation-results-in-err-invalid-response-in-chrome

Comment: yap, i using chrome browser. and i have added my code..

Comment: @Scuzzy, can you show detail how can i add content type in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  Excel::create("Customers", function ($excel){
  $excel->setTitle("Example Sheet");
  $excel->sheet("Sheet 1", function ($sheet){
        $sheet->row(1, array("NO.","NAME","DATE", "ADDRESS"));
    });
  })->download('xls');
```

Calling the `download` method, instead of `export`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by installing a PHP package. In my case, it's PHP 7.2.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-zip
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fix it downgrade the version of PHP to 7.1. I hope it helps you.